# How to add gift product in checkout with multiple address?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Customer have two products in his/her cart. Now he/she selects different addresses for each product hence, Magento creates two order after successful checkout. But As per requirement i need to add Gift product (which can be added statically. Fixed SKU is given) for each order. So, we need to add GIFT product on different address.

We are not aware of this scenario. We haven't found any way to complete this task. So please suggest a way.

Comment: Are you trying to configure Magento or are you wanting to write your own extension?

Comment: @Enigmativity My first preference is to configure to magento. if not possible then i am open to right extension as well.